# Windows Azure Parameters

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, azure

Folks, Good Night! Can you halp me in this situation ?
I search for two days, but I cant't find a way to do this ...

How can I pass parameters to read function in Windows Azure mobile service ?

In code bellow I call the read function , but I want pass Parm1 to manipulate in Windos Azure.

```
[itemTable readWhere:predicate completion:^(NSArray *items, NSInteger totalCount, NSError *error) {
```

I want in Windows Azure make something like this...

```
function read(query, user, request) {
var parm1 = query.parameters.Parm1;

request.execute();
}
```

Tks for help me.

Paulo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're doing a read, this can be accomplished by calling MSTable's readWithQueryString method.  For example:

```
NSString *queryString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"param1=%@", @"myparam"];

[self.myTable readWithQueryString:queryString completion:^...
```

and then in your server side scripts you would acces sit using request.parameters.param1.

Chris

Comment: Hello Chris, Tks for help.
I implement the code but didnt work...

In Xcode:
` NSString *queryString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"param1=%@", @"myparam"];
    NSLog(@"TestParm %@",queryString);
    //out : TestParm param1=myparam
    [itemTable readWithQueryString:queryString completion:^(NSArray *items, NSInteger totalCount, NSError *error) {
`
In Azure I receved de error:

console.log(query.parameters.param1 );

ERRO Error in script '/table/mpa_posto.read.js'. TypeError: Cannot read property 'param1' of undefined at read (:3:29) at :1:6 [external code]

Can you know why ?

Comment: Sorry Chris, its work ... I was calling query.parameters instead request.parameters ... Tks a lot .. you save my life ;-)